# RABBITMQ - Applying Plugin Failed

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-shovel

**EDIT:** After setting the rabbitmq variables up in System Environment Variables and trying another un/reinstall the issue is resolved.

> The following plugins have been enabled:   rabbitmq_shovel
>
> Applying plugin configuration to rabbit@MSGTEST01... started 1 plugin.

**END EDIT**

> c:\RabbitMQ\rabbitmq_server-3.6.12\sbin>rabbitmq-plugins enable
>   rabbitmq_shovel rabbitmq_shovel_management Plugin configuration
>   unchanged.
>
> Applying plugin configuration to rabbit@M... failed. Error:
>   {enabled_plugins_mismatch,"c:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\RabbitMQ
>   \ENABLE~1",
>                                    "c:\RabbitMQ\ENABLE~1"}

I set the following then reinstalled the service:

```
set RABBITMQ_BASE=c:\RabbitMQ
set RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILE=c:\RabbitMQ\rabbitmq
set RABBITMQ_LOG_BASE=c:\RabbitMQ\logs
set RABBITMQ_MNESIA_BASE=c:\RabbitMQ\db
set RABBITMQ_ENABLED_PLUGINS_FILE=c:\RabbitMQ\enabled_plugins
```

Why is it still looking in my roaming profile for anything? Moreover, ENABLE~1 doesn't look like a valid filename.

- I've tried blowing away my roaming profile data, RabbitMQ recreates the files.
- I've tried copying my C:\RabbitMQ\enables_plugins to roaming, same thing.
- Tried the reverse, same thing.
- I've tried uninstalling and resintalling the service, same thing.

I'm able to enable the management ui after install, but not rabbitmq_shovel and cannot figure out what the issue is.

Again, this works after install:

```
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
```

This fails with the error above:

```
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_shovel
```

I'm running these commands as Admin in CMD.

Comment: Currently, I'm in the process of added all the rabbitmq variables into my System Envrionment Variables and going to try a reinstall that way.

Comment: Perhaps, for whatever reason, my last set command wasn't taking: set RABBITMQ_ENABLED_PLUGINS_FILE=c:\RabbitMQ\enabled_plugins. But if that is the case, why was it reporting that location in the mismatch. Really not sure what happened here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up the variables in System Environment Variables and perform the following in CMD as Admin:

- rabbitmqctl shutdown
- rabbitmqctl stop
- rabbitmq-service.bat remove
- rabbitmq-service.bat install
- rabbitmq-service.bat start
- rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
- rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_shovel

That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue without having to uninstall RabbitMQ

Open the files named "enabled_plugins" at the two directory locations int he error your recived.  For me, those directories were "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\RabbitMQ" and "C:\ProgramData\RabbitMQ".

For me, one file had:

```
    [rabbitmq_management].
```

while the other was empty.  I copied the config snippet above into the empty file and saved it.

Run the commands as ADMIN in Command Prompt:

```
    rabbitmqctl shutdown
    rabbitmqctl stop
    rabbitmq-service.bat start
    rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
```

I did receive the same "enabled_plugins_mismatch" error; however, when I browsed to my RabbitMQ UI plugin at "http://localhost:15672/#/" the UI showed up and is functioning.